# Access file:/// using steroids.js

Tags: android, cordova, steroids

I am unable to access the filesystem using steroid.js. I have used the exact same code within phonegap and do not have the issue. here is my code and I do not appear to get any errors in my console.

```
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {
        if(data.duration > 10) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(mediaFiles[0].fullPath, FileRemoveSuccess, function() {
                navigator.notification.alert('Error: Unable to access file system')
            });
        }
        else{
            $('#video-content').append('<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="' + mediaFiles[0].fullPath + '" type="video/mp4"></video><br><span>' + mediaFiles[0].fullPath + '</span>');
        }
    });
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
function RecordVideo(){
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {duration:10});
}
```

I have also tried to access an image by putting in the path manually or a video and I have the same issues. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're serving your app via localhost (e.g. `steroids.config.location = http://localhost/index.html`, then built-in WebKit security will block assets from `file:///`, since it's in a different domain. Is that the case? We're working on a solution for all CORS issues, but see http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids-js/app-structure-on-device/ for information on how a Steroids app is structured on the device (and thus how you can access files via localhost).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that not only your index.html file needs to be served as a file but so do any other webviews you create using the `new steroids.views.WebView` command. Once I corrected this, the issue was resolved